# Imams mispronouncing/changing words in al Fatiha?

Tags: salat, fiqh, quran-recitation

Al salam alaykom, I have been to two prayers where the imams mispronounced or changed words in Al Fatiha. Can anyone please let me know if these errors invalidate the prayer?

The first one was on Jumah and the khutba was about taqwa. In the prayer itself the imam said "Ihdina siraat al muttaqeen."

The second one was when an imam said, at the end of al Fatiha "Wala al dhaaleen" instead of "wala al daaleen."

Comment: If you are Arabic speaker and could pronounce it well you shouldn't pray behind them and you should try to explain their mistakes and teach them. As this is an error in recitation that is sinful (Lahn jaliy)! The validity of their prayer and that of those who pray behind them is doubtful.

Comment: Asta3'fir Allah. I will do my best, but I usually pray in the back and can't correct them without having to shout. I live in an Arabic speaking country and this is the closest mosque to my house.

Comment: I mean you should seek an opportunity to speak to them and tell them. As hiding knowledge is also sinful. If they don't accept you have at least done your due. But maybe we should wait for a good answer with helpful evidences.

Comment: You're right, next time it happens I should talk to them about it. If they don't accept it, can I still pray there? I was once told that the imam holds responsibility for the prayer of those he leads, so if he errs, it falls on him and not the others praying. Do you know if that correct?